# Spring boot project can not recognize after Windows blue screen Crash

Tags: java, spring, windows, maven, intellij-idea

I had a windows crash with blue screen as often happens. in this time my Intellij-Idea Data is gone and reset to default value and also my project data. so Intellij-Idea do not recognize my project as Spring-boot and I can not Run it.

I reimporetd the project, it is not working. clean, clear cache, Invadidate and restart and result was same. I check the project structure and see every dependency in module is gone although all dependency is still in my `pom.xml` ! so how I can fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a broken HDD/SSD. Time to replace it before moving on.

Comment: Delete `.idea` directory from the project and reimport it by opening `pom.xml`.

Comment: I also delte the local cache files like .idea but nothings change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this problem by re Installing **JDK**. I find out that JDK is damaged by Windows blue screen cause the Intellij Idea even do not recognize Java classes of project like `String`.

after install last version of JDK every things worked fine.

Comment: Again, this sounds like a failing disk drive. You need to replace it as soon as possible. If re-installing the JDK appears to have solved the problem for you, then you were merely lucky, and the pieces of code you run have been copied into blocks that are still healthy. Check the *Event Viewer* to see the reports of faulting hardware.

Comment: @IInspectable I always get blue screen when some heavy app processing togetherfor example Intellij Idea and two project on Android studio and when anto virus automatically scan starts suddenly this crash hapens.I have core i7 cpu with 16GB of ram and two hard discs, one of them is SSD and windows installed on it.

Comment: `BugCheck`s happen for 2 cases: Hardware defects and driver issues. If the error code is somewhat random, it's an indication of the former, while the latter often produces reproducible codes (although malware infections at the driver level can cause fairly random codes as well). At any rate, they are indicative of severe issues with your system and must be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to click the *Reimport all maven projects* button in the maven projects view , the circled arrows.

[image: maven project view]

As a last possibility you can try - after closing IntelliJ - to delete from your project directory the **.iml* file defining the IntelliJ project and the *.idea* folder. As this folder name starts with a dot, it's a hidden directory in some OS, so the best thing is to do this from a shell.

After that start IntelliJ and do a *File/Open...* and select the pom (or the directory containing the pom) to recreate the project.

Hope that helps.